# Python flask is not returning the correct values when deploying on production

Tags: python, flask

I am facing a strange problem. I have two environment one is test and another is production. The test is nothing but `localhost:5002` and runs on my laptop. 
The production is `192.XXX.XXX.XX:5002`.

I have `deploy.py` file running absolutely fine on test. But the same file when I am deploying on Production, it is not returning the `response` function value correctly. Besides, the hyperlink is also not working correctly. Below is the code snippet for `deploy.py`for production.

```
def email_url(text):
    new_s = re.sub('[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w+', lambda x:f'<a href="mailto: 
    {x.group()}">{x.group()}</a>', text)
    new_s = new_s.replace('xx.yyyy.com','<a href = 
    "http://xx.yyyy.com:8080">xx.yyyy.com</a>')
    return new_s


@app.route('/response/',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def response():   
      #---code goes here----
      return email_url(resp) #resp is a string with few words are clickable
if __name__ == "__main__":
      print("**Starting Server...")

      app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5002, debug=True)
```

I am expecting same `email_url(resp)` value for both test and production. But I am getting different. Besides the hyperlink is working fine in test i.e. `localhost:5002` but not working on production i.e. `192.xxx.xxx.xx:5002`

So what I am missing out here? I am using Windows 8.1 for both test and production.

Comment: How do you deploy your app? Have you tried turning debug logging in your production app? Is there anything strange in those logs? Also, please fix indents in your question's code.

Comment: I deploy on a local server whose IP is given. Indents have been fixed

Comment: Is the above problem is due to Two different version in python being used? In production it is 3.7 but in test it is 3.6

Answer (score 0):

So I have finally nailed down this problem. It was "indeed" the version issues. The model and pickle files from sklearn version 0.20 on Test, but 0.19 in production.